# How to delete an a sub object from an abstract super class in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework, to delete an object we do this:

```
model delObj = new model { ID = id };
db.model.Attach(delObj);
db.model.Remove(delObj);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Right now, I have a problem .. class `model` is actually an abstract class and it is the actual table in the database.

In C#, I made two sub classes so I don't exactly know which sub-object is supposed to be deleted since `id` is assigned at runtime.

The above code doesn't work anymore because model is abstract and now I can't make "an object from an abstract class"

How do I delete a sub object using the abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few possible options depending on your requirements:

1) retrieve the object before deleting. Down side - extra query, although not always a bad thing to check if you are actually deleting something.

```
var found = db.model.first(x=>x.ID==id);
if (found != null) {    
db.Remove(found); 
db.SaveChangesAsync();    
}
```

2) Don't make your base class Abstract. I don't know your reasons for making the base class abstract, but I would think whether it is actually required.

3) If you are certain you need an abstract class, and/or don't want to query first use a direct SQL command.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()
```